# Sorting Names Alphabetically In C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have this code in my computer book:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 
#include<string.h>
void main(void)
{
    clrscr();
    char list[10][20],name[20];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the Name of Student %d",i+1);
        gets(&list[i][0]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<10-1;i++)
        for(j=0;j<10-1;j++)
            if(strcmp(&list[j][0],&list[j+1][0])>0)
            {
                strcpy(name,&list[j][0]);
                strcpy(&list[j][0],&list[j+1][0]);
                strcpy(&list[j+1][0],name);
            }
    printf("\nThe Sorted Name List is :");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("\n%s",&list[i][0]);
    getche();
}
```

I would like to know why the array "list" is declared as list[10][20] but when it is used to store the names it uses only 1 loop i.e only i and the 2nd index or subscript is always kept zero while it is 20 in the declaration?!

Comment: if the code really contains `gets()`, time to get a better book..really...

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: hahaha the book "is" old though ;)

Comment: Time to start reading. And by the way, `0` there means the first member.

Comment: @MGB eh...well... no, it is **not** idented. Look how the code in your C textbokk looks like, then look at _your_ code. See the difference ?

Comment: Yeah 0 means the first member. The code is fine i've tested it. The only thing I would like to know is why is there a [20] in the declaration of array list if it is not be used in the loop :/

Comment: @MGB now it is (poorly) idented..

Comment: You would understand the code anyways :) :p

Comment: That sorting algorithm is pretty bad. It looks like a variation on a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It's O(n^2) meaning if the size of the list doubles it will take quadruple the time to sort. You might be better off with something more up to date like [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/).

Comment: Infact it is written in the book that the algorithm is bad for sorting but here it serves as a good example for arrays and string :)

Comment: I allowed myself to improve indentation - have a look at the source to see how to do better, it might help you in future questions.

Comment: @Aconcagua So is it the size of the names that we want to sort?

Comment: No - it is the content of the strings within the array of strings. Imagine you would have used C++ - then you would have had `::std::string list[10];`, or Java: `String[] list = new String[10];`. You do not need to know about these string classes in those two languages - only need to know that they represent textual data (= strings). In C you have no other way as to represent a string as a char* or char[], so if you have an array of strings, you have char*[] or char[][].

Comment: Oh, so it's because C treats strings as an array of characters?

Comment: @MGB Exactly. Actually, any other language does so, too, but in general, this is hidden away from you.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for your kind help. Now I got an idea about it :D

Answer (score 2):

"list" is intended to be used as an array of c strings, but each such string itself is an array of char again, so you get a two-dimentional array, where the "outer" dimenstion represents the strings and the "inner" dimenstion an array to store the string at (with maximal length of 20 characters).

As gets shall fill in such a string, it uses already the entire "inner" dimension, so you have only to loop through the "outer" dimension.